# Is there a way to traverse and select all vectors connected to a starting vector?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector

Preferably using QGis I'd like to remove errors from a road network .shp file and was wondering if there was a away to perform a flood fill or traversal on a vector layer to select all connected vertexes from the starting vertex to do basic validation and remove unconnected roads.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm a bit slow in understanding what you mean. Maybe you can include a picture depicting your question/problem.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do this in QGIS, but you could use the Sextante-Plugin to do this within GrassGIS.

The command you are searching for is:

```
v.select [-tcr] ainput=name [atype=string[,string,...]] [alayer=integer] binput=name [btype=string[,string,...]] [blayer=integer] output=name [operator=string] [--overwrite] [--verbose] [--quiet]
```

A nice tutorial:
[Combination of areas with areas](http://www.ing.unitn.it/~grass/docs/tutorial_62_en/htdocs/esercitazione/geoprocessing/node2.html)

... and the grass manual:
[v.select](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.select.html)